# resize png's in haskell on windows

Tags: haskell, imagemagick, png, mingw, gd

i need http://hackage.haskell.org/package/imagemagick or http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gd-3000.7.3 or similar on windows/mingw (64 bit, but 32 ok) to resize png's.  i can't find step-by-step instructions to get them installed.

i tried mingw-get, but it doesn't seem to have imagemagick or gd.  and i'm not clear on whether just installing the c libraries is enough for cabal to link to them, it says:
"The pkg-config package ImageMagick is required but it could not be found."
and i'm not sure how pkg-config works or relates to mingw-get.  in any case, imagemagick's configure script fails in mingw:
"cannot compute sizeof (long double)"

config.log is chock full of errors, but this seems to be this one:
"ld.exe: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied"

though it seems to write to that file a million times earlier just fine...

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.0 can load/save png's, but doesn't have a nice resize algorithm.

Comment: JuicyPixels (or JuicyPixels-repa ) is indeed the right tool for the job, but you will probably have to write your own resize routine.  The next-best solutions would be one of the bindings to C libraries, but I'm not sure which ones perform resize operations (ex: imagemagik, devil, etc).  For what it's worth, I'd be happy to accept image operations as patches to juicypixels-repa.

Comment: gd and imagemagick do have resize.  decent resizing is easy, but i feel it's adhoc to throw that in without some general affine transform/filtering/antialiasing framework, etc., which i don't have time to do, and would rather not duplicate existing algorithms in standard packages.  any idea how to get gd/imagemagick installed in mingw?  or bind into them from juicypixels?

Comment: Magick would be an alternative to JuicyPixels, not in addition.  You can find bindings on hackage (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsmagick).  As for installing the C library I can't help you there.  If windows users donated $5 every time there is an issue installing a C library then there would probably be a fully featured community supported windows package manager by now.

Comment: > Magick would be an alternative to JuicyPixels, not in addition.

i meant regarding your request for juicypixels contributions that would duplicate algorithms that already exist elsewhere -- i recommend that juicypixels bind existing work rather than duplicate it.  btw, what was the motivation for juicypixels, given that imagemagick and gd already existed?

Comment: > You can find bindings on hackage (hackage.haskell.org/package/hsmagick).

i put a link to the imagemagick bindings on hackage in my original question -- they looked better than hsmagick to me, is there a reason to prefer hsmagick?  it is no easier to install on windows...

Comment: You can feel free to fork JuicyPixels and somehow combine it with an existing library - not sure what that would mean seeing as JP's functionality is subsumed by the C libraries we are discussing.  As for the magick bindings, I have no reason to prefer on over another.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice resize algorithm for JuicyPixels available here: https://gist.github.com/eflister/5456125

That should suffice to accomplish this.

Comment: ha ha, thanks for the complement (esp from the mighty sclv), turns out i *am* eflister.  ;)  i forget ever posting that gist, how did you find it?

Comment: @user1441998 hah! could you mark this as accepted (or alternately just post your own and accept it?) -- i'm looking to close out the unresolved questions :-)

Comment: well...  it was truly about imagemagick/gd linking on windows (ie, not duplicating existing tech), or at least an efficient general affine transform (the gist is naive and inefficient as discussed there) -- so i consider it still unsolved.  you're trying to get all haskell questions closed out?

Comment: @user1441998 -- the closable ones at least. if you consider this legit still open I'm not going to complain :-)

Comment: I would not recomment JuicyPixels for this job.  It's been 4 years since it was suggested here, and JuicyPixels still cannot round-trip metadata which is something you *really* want when you resize images. If not, you will find your images to be randomly rotated if captured in landscape or portrait mode on various devices that represent this information in Exif for example.